# HTML5 Video - Shadow DOM - Change CSS styles

Tags: css, google-chrome, html5-video, shadow-dom

I want to style the slider thumb of video control in Chrome.
The css path

```
video::-webkit-media-slider-thumb
```

doesn't work.

Playground: http://jsfiddle.net/holden321/27fUR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline::-webkit-media-slider-thumb {
    background:red; /* works */
}
```

That's because slider-thumb is "child" of timeline :)

Comment: Not working for me anymore :/ (chrome 48).
Updated playground: http://jsfiddle.net/27fUR/20/