# Change audio background color in HTML5 using css

Tags: html, css

I searched so many thing but didnot find any useful document..I want to change background-color of audio tag as I know `background-color` is enough but its not working..Is there any solution to change it or is it possible to change?I do not want to use any plugin..just using by CSS I want to change..

Code:

```
<audio controls="">
  <source src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom CSS for <audio> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794682/custom-css-for-audio-tag)

Comment: @andrescpacheco please read my question first before down vote..I do not need any plugin only css..I also saw that link..If I used that then audio will be like https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/pzdg2pjp/1/  ...I want to change background color only

Comment: first line of the accepted answer: "There is not currently any way to style HTML5 <audio> players using CSS."

Comment: Yeah that was written before six years ago that's why my question's last line is `is it possible?`

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't possible. Why not develop a custom audio player?

Comment: I was giving a try if it's possible now..Thanks for your time :)

Comment: you you notice it is working... https://jsfiddle.net/rajsharma1612/eg6ghhge/

Comment: But it works differently on different browsers..

Comment: The problem is that each browser has a different way to deal with <audio> that's why you are getting different behaviors.

Comment: if you doesn't have a problem with supporting only webkit browsers then you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35262548/6213434   example: https://jsfiddle.net/eg6ghhge/1/

Comment: I tried that...It will work only in chrome..what about other browsers?

Comment: @RajSharma it will mix with black try using `#FFFFFF`

Comment: @El.oz Thankyou for link but Its must support by all broswers..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

Answer (score 17):

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
     audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
     background-color: #000;
     color: #000;
     }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Would this work in non-webkit browsers like Firefox ? The webkit tags don't seem very reliable without some added polyfills or equivalents for other types of browsers

Answer (score 4):

> is it possible to change?
>
> just using by CSS

**the short answer is no, It's NOT possible**.

the audio player is an object created ***by the browser*** itself, that's why it looks different depending on the browser you use.

if you want to customize the player in a way that work with all browsers without using 3rd party plugins or scripts you'll need to customize and handle it yourself.

it's fairly simple using [This DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

you'll need to hide the default player and create your own buttons and refer to the audio object.

for examplle you can give your audio object an id like "myAudio"

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls="">
  <source src="http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

now you control it using Javascript and the reference I linked above

```
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
x.play();
// OR
x.pause()
```

and you can listen to its [Media Events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) too

```
x.onended = function(){
   //do something when audio ends
};
```

creating an advanced player with seeking and timers would take more effort and time but should be strait forward and easy.

if you don't want to go through the hassle of creating your own buttons and functions you'll have to get a plugin and customize its CSS if necessary.

**More inforamtion:**

[HTML5 audio in detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Cross-browser_audio_basics#HTML5_audio_in_detail)

[Creating your own custom audio player](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Cross-browser_audio_basics#Creating_your_own_custom_audio_player)

[HTML Audio/Video DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

Answer (score 0):

close enough that you can just add a nice reduce with

```
        .mfaudio{
            background-color: var(--pink);/*no work :(*/
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 2em;
        }
```