# How can I make the default audioplayer background be transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the background for the audio player be transparent. With the thing I tried I can change the color to any color but it wasn't working when I put transparent.

```css
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
     audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
     background-color: transparent;
     }
```

Comment: do you mean, you need it to disappear?

Comment: it literally says in there its possible and shows my exact way of changing the background color, my question is if it lets me change the background color why can't i make it transparent

Comment: You could use opacity to make it transparent

Comment: how would that work and can you give like a quick line of code which i could try

Comment: instead of giving transparent just give the main background to the audio, it will update the same color. Eg: my body tag background is white so I applied #fff to "audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
     audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #fff;
     }"

Comment: i tried it but it just gave like a light gray when i set the opacity to 0

Comment: @Snow: Im doing that currently but the problem is that i have a like a box which the color is blue, and then a white background for the body, the audio player is in the blue box, when the screen size gets smaller the audioplayer sticks out the blue box

Answer (score 1):

Like @snow said, you can't make the background transparent but you could make its opacity 0
something like this:

```
audio{
  opacity: 0%;
}
```

Comment: i cant because it just make it light gray

Comment: what do you mean it makes it light gray, did you add the opacity directly to the object selector?

Comment: actually i tried again its working now it a cache problem or something

Comment: one more thing it now makes the whole thing transparent is it possible to make the play button appear again or select the playbutton and change the color to black

Comment: you could try to add callback function/pseudo-element selector to set the opacity back

Comment: how would i approach that

Comment: its another question, so post it again.

Comment: ok thx will do rn but if you can find like an example of how it works or give me like a website it would be very helpful

Comment: btw, can you accept the answer if it solved the problem?

Comment: its not really solved because i said in the question how to make the background transparent not the whole thing

Comment: You still don't understand what snow explained, if you really want to change style of the audio tag why not build a custom player that overrides the function of the audio tag.

Answer (score 0):

[is it possible to change just using CSS? the short answer is no, It's NOT possible. An audio player is an object created by the browser itself, that's why it looks different depending on the browser you use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339440/change-audio-background-color-in-html5-using-css)

You can apply the same background color to the audio tag if your parent or body background is white you need to apply the same for audio

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
 audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #fff;
 
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Im doing that currently but the problem is that i have a like a box which the color is blue, and then a white background for the body, the audio player is in the blue box, when the screen size gets smaller the audioplayer sticks out the blue box

Comment: Could you post the design on your question that you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want the audioplayer to be transparent but the play button to be there and have a black color