# how to change the color of default chromium music player?

Tags: javascript, css, web, google-web-designer, sitedesign

I have a weblog and I want to change the color of default chromium music player for my visitors.
the default chromium music player is this:
[image: default chromium music player]

I want to make it another color (to be shown on my weblog) but I don't know how : (

thanks in advance.

Comment: Right click the element, in the context menu click on ‘inspect’, in the DOM window that’s produced look for the various selectors you might use.

Comment: I know it's not nice to just say what might not be working, but because it's a browser created component changing the style from within the website usually does not work nor does the inspection of it due to the shadow dom (unless you change it in chrome dev tools settings).
Edit: Did you try the answers given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259242/css-style-audio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, this browser created component of google chrome cannot be changed by within the website yet.
one way is to build your own music player like this and change the color.